# code is working in windows but not in linux

Tags: javascript, xml, linux

I have written a code in javascript that works absolutely fine in windows .It takes xml as input and uses jqplot plugins to display data in the form of piecharts.

When I run this code in linux, no output is shown. If static data is given as input it works in linux also. But if xml is given as input it doesnt .

I am pasting only the very few initial lines to give an idea.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","report.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
xmlObj=xmlDoc.documentElement;

var b=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SC_PROCESS");
```

rest of the code is similar having tags like `getElementsByTagName("SC_PROCESS")` to extract data.

Comment: What browsers are you using (in windows and in Linux)? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure that the file name is `report.xml` and not `Report.xml` or `REPORT.XML` or ...

Comment: ya i am sure. the same code works in windows .

Comment: @Oded - There is no error . It runs and shows no output.

Comment: Do you have it all on a web server? You can't do XMLHttpRequest on the local filesystem (in some older browsers you can), it has to be done through the web server (preferably in the same domain).

Comment: I Am using firefox 3.0 on Linux using local file system. I dont have any access to a web server. i have confirmed the execution stops at the line ""xmlhttp.send();"".

Comment: From W3C prospective, both methods documentElement and getElementsByTagName are cross browser compliant, so I guess your problem occurs before this step. You might use firebug to check what is returned by your server to your client.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of problems are normally caused by using case-insensitive file names, e.g., saving a file as `Report.xml` and calling it as `report.xml`. In order to write multiplatform code you need to always use the same case.

Comment: thank you for replying. I have checked ,the file names are all correct(case wise also).

Comment: I don't know how you tested so but I suggest to: 1) Look at the web server's error log 2) Use Firebug's Net panel